# Finding a closed formula for: $1\cdot2\cdot3+2\cdot3\cdot4+...+(n-2)\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-verification

As I calculated the sum of the serie above doesn't exist(sum doesn't converge). How can I prove it using the double computing(combinatorical method)?

Comment: Are you asking for an explicit formula?

Comment: yes, but I think it doesn't exist

Comment: Certainly, the limit as $n$ approaches infinity will not converge (*how could it? the limit of the summands does not approach zero*).  The question title implies that you are wishing to find a closed form for the partial sums, while the body of the question seems to imply that you wish to prove that the series doesn't converge.

Comment: The example sounds exactly so: Find a closed formula for the next sum... I've checked that this serie is convergent, so I thought that a closed formula doesn't exist.

Comment: In general, you can use [Faulhaber's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html) upon expanding the summand.

Comment: All sums of the form

$$\sum_{k=1}^nP(k),$$ were $P$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ can be expressed in a closed-form, which is a polynomial in $n$ of the degree $d+1$.

This can be established using the Faulhaber formula, or more directly.

Let
$$Q(n):=\sum_{k=1}^nP(k).$$

Then

$$Q(n)-Q(n-1)=P(n).$$

By identifying the coefficients, you obtain a linear system of $d+1$ equations in $d+1$ unkowns $q_1,q_2,\cdots q_{d+1}$ (indeed, $Q(0)=q_0=0$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the hockey stick identity.

What we want is $\sum_{i=3}^{n}\binom{n}{3}6$

It is a known fact $\sum_{i=k}^n\binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$

Hence $\sum_{i=3}^{n}i(i-1)(i-2)=6\binom{n+1}{4}$